# How to open iTerm from the terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: iterm2, iterm

I tried the command `iterm .` but it says `zsh: command not found: iterm`.

How can I create a shortcut for iterm so I can open it from other terminal tools?

Pretty much I want `open -a iTerm .` to be shortern to `iterm .` but I don't want to use the alias because it seems too hacky.

Comment: Why do you think an alias for this would feel hacky?

Answer (score 2):

open the `.zshrc` file using Vim or Vs Code.

For Vs Code, use `code ~/.zshrc`

For Vim, use `vim ~/.zshrc`

inside the opened file, add this function to it probably anywhere before the end of the last line

```
iterm() {

    open -a iTerm "$*"

}
```

Refresh the terminal with this command `source ~/.zshrc` .

Now when you type `iterm` in your terminal, this will open the iTerm app

**Note:** the `"$*"` in the function above represents any argument of string you pass after typing `iterm` in your terminal.

By default, it points to the current folder VS Code is on, thus you can open iterm in another folder like taking your Desktop for an example.

Type `iterm  ~/Desktop` , this will open the iTerm app and the Desktop folder will be its current working directory

Answer (score 1):

For people that want to use alias:

ZSH: `alias iterm="open -a iTerm $*"`